# Mixed repeated measures Anova

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, diversity

I'm trying to assess the influence of fertilisation and irrigation on biodiversity in a complete randomized block design. I have two treatments, one control and two blocks. Treatments went on for three years so I have three repeated measures. I want to find out if biodiversity is significantly different for the treatments; #1 in the single years and #2 over all three years.

I think that repeated measures anova should do the job, however, I'm struggling on how to include the blocks in the calculation. Would it be appropriate to calculate a mean over the blocks before doing an anova? Is there another way to do this?